# passing a string in a constructor derived from a thread class

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor, pthreads

I would like to be able to change the name of a thread when it actually gets created through the class called A_thread_class which is derived from the std class thread.The new thread should be named before the "intended" thread function is called, and before the constructor returns.

In my example below I would like to change the thread name to "Thread01" in that manner. 
When I run my current implementation I get compiling error even though the code is showing no error. 
How can I achieve this ? and fix my compiling error ?
My compiling error is :
          usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class

```
   template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
   void helperFunc(const std::string &name, _Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args){

        // setting  name here

      pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), (char*) &name);
       // do something else
   }
   class A_thread_class : public std::thread
   {

   private :
   template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
   thread thread_function(const std::string &name,_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) {


   thread th;
   th = std::thread([&]{helperFunc(name, std::forward<_Callable>(__f), std::forward<_Args> 
          (__args)...);});

        }

    public:

    using thread::thread;

    template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    explicit
    A_thread_class (const std::string &name,_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) :
        std::thread(thread_function( &name,_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args){}
    }


    void aThreadFunc(void){
    //blah blah implementation
    }

    int main(){


    A_thread_class aThread("Thread01", aThreadFunc);
    aThread.join();

    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Unlikely to be a cause for the concrete issue at hand, but important: Identifiers containing double underscores and identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the C++ implementation in all scopes and may not be declared by a program. Doing so causes undefined behavior.

Comment: `(char*) &name` is also causing undefined behavior. I think you intended `name.c_str()`.

Comment: You cut off the error message. Please include the complete compiler output verbatim.

Comment: The first error in the chain is: `/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/thread:119:2: error: static_assert failed due to requirement '__is_invocable<const char *, void (*)()>::value' "std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues"` So something is going wrong, when you try to call the passedn function.

Comment: Furthermore: 1. You are missing a closing `)` in the `A_thread_class` constructor. 2. `_Callable&&` and `&name` in the constructor make no sense, the second one isn't even syntactically valid. 3. `thread_function` claims to return a `std::thread` but doesn't do so. 4. `thread_function` tries to create a new thread instead of just invocing `helper_func`. 5. `thread_function` does not run `helper_function` in a thread but just calls it instead and tries to run its `void` return value as thread (which doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the constructor of `std::thread`, then you should not inherit the constructor with `using thread::thread`.

As it stands, you are constructing your class with a `const char(&)[]` referring to the string literal as the first parameter. The variadic forwarding constructor for `std::thread` is therefore a better match than the constructor for `A_thread_class` that you declare here, which takes a `std::string` as the first argument, thus requiring a user-defined conversion.

If you remove the `using` then the `std::thread` constructors are no longer visible, and you can define only the constructors you desire.